# How effectively develop Azure blueprints?

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I'm starting to develop Azure blueprints and I can see that structure of ARM template is different compared to one used in ARM deployment. I like to modularize code and trying to figure out how I can properly develop individual ARM templates and then incorporate into final blueprint properly. As of right now instead of directly putting ARM artifact into blueprint (along with 100 others) I just manually debug ARM template and then cut in paste into artifact. I'm wondering if there is more effective way doing that or I missing something? Based on documentation it seems to be suggested directly incorporate templates into artifacts then deploy/publish/assign blueprint which takes way to much when you just need to work on single ARM template

Answer (score 0):

An effective / dynamic / automated way can be accomplished by leveraging this [Blueprints as Code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-blueprints) repository for management and dynamic way of configuring lifecycle of your blueprints which helps in reducing the effort compared to Portal way of managing the blueprints.

Other related references:

- [Functions for use with Blueprints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/blueprints/reference/blueprint-functions)
- [Blueprints REST API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/blueprints/)
- [Blueprints Az PowerShell Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.blueprint/?view=azps-3.8.0#blueprint)